# Changing Color of Linux Terminal Directory shown on command line

Tags: bash, terminal, ls

I am trying to customize my terminal colors on my Macbook Pro. Using the Terminal app I adjusted my preferences for background color, text, and I made changes to the ANSI colors. I also specify `export CLICOLOR=1`  and `export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagacad` for the ANSI colors in my `~/.bash_profile` file and then source it. When I use the `ls` command it lists the directories in the correct color that I wanted (blue, as seen in the picture). However, if I `cd` into a directory the directory path on the command line is not one of my specified ANSI colors (it's purple, as seen in the picture). Is there something else I need to make a change to in order to change that color setting to be the same blue that is used for `ls`? I do not know very much about bash and ANSI colors, so I apologize if I incorrectly used certain terminology.
[Terminal Example Picture Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1evO.png)
[ANSI Color Settings Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oW9ZB.png)

Comment: [unix.se] or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) are more appropriate places to ask questions about configuring and using UNIX tools. Stack Overflow is only for questions about _writing software_.

Comment: That said -- ANSI colors are an old and limited specification; earlier versions had only 3 or 4 bits of data, and so were limited to a palette of 8 or 16 colors _total_ (and the man page for GNU `ls` implies that it's implementing only that 16-color original palette). It's not surprising at all for you to have a terminal that supports far more colors than the legacy ANSI color spec can honor.

Comment: If you want software to help guide you in setting a `LSCOLORS` value that uses more than the 16-color palette that the man page describes, you might start with https://github.com/sharkdp/vivid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, if I cd into a directory the directory path on the command line is not one of my specified ANSI colors (it's purple, as seen in the picture).

The command line prompt does not care about `LSCOLORS`, its look is defined by variable `PS1`. To get your current `PS1` value, use:

```
declare -p PS1
```

Mine looks like this (yours might differ):

```
declare -- PS1="\\[\\e]0;\\u@\\h:\\w\\a\\]\\[\\e[1;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\[\\e[1;34m\\] [\\w] \\\$\\[\\e[0m\\] "
```

To change the color of the directory part, modify the escape sequence right before `[\\w]`, e.g. change `\\[\\e[1;34m\\]` to `\\[\\e[1;33m\\]` for yellow.

To make changes permanent, add the new `PS1` setting to your `.bash_profile` as well.